# Hello everyone! I'm looking for a PC program to help me learn particular words

Tags: vocabulary, learning

So, I see such a program this way: in the first field I input some words in English, in the second one I input their translations. Then the program RANDOMLY shows me words in English I inputed earlier, I input their translations, and the program says if my answer was right or wrong. I guess it can be done vice versa, so the program shows me translations in my native language, I input English versions of it, etc. Does such a program exist? Or maybe a website?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources.

Comment: Anki is great! But this isn't the right site for asking this. Try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Zinger vocabulary builder chrome extension.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zinger/fcpibijcomgjkeecnmjkkjfcnfnaldin?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, Anki turned out to be more fitting to my needs :)